# How to run airflow 2.0+ with openlineage and marquez in docker?

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm trying to running the DAG in [this](https://github.com/MarquezProject/marquez/tree/main/examples/airflow) example with airflow 2.0+. I setup an airflow project on docker following [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) example, and I want to integrate it with openlieage. I wonder how can I do that? I set environment variables for openlineage in the .env file that looks like below:

[image]

I git cloned the marquez repo on github and get marquez running following the [readme](https://github.com/MarquezProject/marquez). I suppose openlineage will listen on port 5000, and marquez will listen on port 5000, but when I browse localhost:3000, which is the UI of marquez, it shows no jobs found.

Here is my project directory:
[image]

Here is my yaml file, which is exactly the same as this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html):

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.3.2
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.2}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

and this is my current .env file:
[image]

error message:

```
hdee@openlineageDEV:~/airflow-docker$ sudo docker-compose up airflow-init                                                                                                           
WARNING: Found orphan containers (airflow-docker_marquez_1, airflow-
docker_marquez_web_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this 
service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --
remove-orphans flag to clean it up.airflow-docker_redis_1 is up-to-date                                                                                      
airflow-docker_postgres_1 is up-to-date                                                                                                                                              
Starting airflow-docker_airflow-init_1 ... done                                                                                                                                      
Attaching to airflow-docker_airflow-init_1                                                                                                                                           
airflow-init_1       | The container is run as root user. For security, 
consider using a regular user account.                                                                       
airflow-init_1       | ....................                                                                                                                                          
airflow-init_1       | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.                                                                                                                
airflow-init_1       |                                                                                                                                                               
airflow-init_1       | Last check result:                                                                                                                                            
airflow-init_1       | $ airflow db check                                                                                                                                            
airflow-init_1       | [2022-06-15 06:30:30,724] {configuration.py:484} 
ERROR - No module named 'openlineage'                                                                        
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                            
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 482, in getimport                                                    
airflow-init_1       |     return import_string(full_qualified_path)                                                                                                                 
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 32, in import_string                                          
airflow-init_1       |     module = import_module(module_path)                                                                                                                       
airflow-init_1       |   File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], 
package, level)                                                                                               
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
994, in _gcd_import                                                                                              
hdee@openlineageDEV:~/airflow-docker$                                                                                                                                                
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
941, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                  
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
994, in _gcd_import                                                                                              
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
971, in _find_and_load                                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
953, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                  
airflow-init_1       | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'openlineage'                                                                                                            
airflow-init_1       |                                                                                                                                                               
airflow-init_1       | During handling of the above exception, another 
exception occurred:                                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |                                                                                                                                                               
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                            
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 
8, in <module>                                                                                                
airflow-init_1       |     sys.exit(main())                                                                                                                                          
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main                                                               
airflow-init_1       |     args.func(args)                                                                                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 47, in command                                                      
airflow-init_1       |     func = import_string(import_path)                                                                                                                         
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 32, in import_string                                          
airflow-init_1       |     module = import_module(module_path)                                                                                                                       
airflow-init_1       |   File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], 
package, level)                                                                                               
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
994, in _gcd_import                                                                                              
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
971, in _find_and_load                                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
955, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                  
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
665, in _load_unlocked                                                                                           
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", 
line 678, in exec_module                                                                                     
airflow-init_1       |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 
219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 24, in <module>                                            
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.utils import cli as cli_utils, 
db                                                                                                            
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 27, in <module>                                                           
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.jobs.base_job import BaseJob  # 
noqa: F401                                                                                                   
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/jobs/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>                                                      
airflow-init_1       |     import airflow.jobs.backfill_job                                                                                                                          
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py", line 28, in <module>                                                  
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow import models                                                                                                                                
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>                                                    
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.models.baseoperator import 
BaseOperator, BaseOperatorLink                                                                                    
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 206, in <module>                                               
airflow-init_1       |     class BaseOperator(Operator, LoggingMixin, 
TaskMixin, metaclass=BaseOperatorMeta):                                                                        
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 999, in BaseOperator                                           
airflow-init_1       |     def post_execute(self, context: Any, result: 
Any = None):                                                                                                 
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/lineage/__init__.py", line 103, in apply_lineage                                             
airflow-init_1       |     _backend = get_backend()                                                                                                                                  
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/lineage/__init__.py", line 52, in get_backend                                                
airflow-init_1       |     clazz = conf.getimport("lineage", "backend", 
fallback=None)                                                                                               
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 486, in getimport                                                    
airflow-init_1       |     f'The object could not be loaded. Please 
check "{key}" key in "{section}" section. '                                                                      
airflow-init_1       | airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: The 
object could not be loaded. Please check "backend" key in "lineage" 
section. Current value: 
"openlineage.lineage_backend.OpenLineageBackend".                                                                                                                                                       
airflow-init_1       |                                                                                                                                                               
airflow-docker_airflow-init_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile ?

Comment: @peerpressure, hi! I'm very new to docker, and I don't know exactly what "dockerfile" means, does it mean the docker-compose.yaml file or should there be a file called "dockerfile" under my working directory?

Comment: @DierHou i need help for the same, is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 1):

To set up the OpenLineage in Airflow, You can add an environment variable in the docker file.

You can add this command in DockerFile

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.2}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    AIRFLOW__LINEAGE__BACKEND :  'openlineage.lineage_backend.OpenLineageBackend'

    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: Can I add "AIRFLOW__LINEAGE__BACKEND =  openlineage.lineage_backend.OpenLineageBackend" to the .env file? Do they work the same?

Comment: Hi, after adding AIRFLOW__LINEAGE__BACKEND =  openlineage.lineage_backend.OpenLineageBackend to my yaml file and running docker-compose up airflow-init, I got an error "no module named openlineage"

Comment: No, you can't add the env variable to the YAML files, Can you share the screenshot of the project directory ?

Comment: I added it in the problem description above. my project directory is ~/airflow-docker.

Comment: I added "AIRFLOW__LINEAGE__BACKEND =  openlineage.lineage_backend.OpenLineageBackend" in the .env file, and then ran "docker-compose up", then I go to the ~/marquez directory and ran "./docker/.up.sh" to start marquez. But when I go to marquez web UI, it shows no jobs running. I seems like marquez didn't "connect" to the airflow jobs running?

Comment: Can you show the content of docker-compose.yaml file?

Comment: Yes, I added that in the description.

Comment: Do I need to add the marquez image in the yaml file?

Comment: can you try adding the `AIRFLOW__LINEAGE__BACKEND =  openlineage.lineage_backend.OpenLineageBackend`  in the enviroment section of the docker-compose.yaml file. And remove the thing from .env file

Comment: ， Yes I've done that, and it says "cannot fine module openlineage"

Comment: I've added the whole error message in the description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245619/discussion-between-peerpressure-and-dier-hou).

Comment: @peerpressure i am also facing the same issue, could you please help me here